# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n(x)$ converges uniformly, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty [ f_n(x)+g_n(x)]$ converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $x\in X$,

then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty [ f_n(x)+g_n(x)]$ converges uniformly on $x\in X$.

---

My working so far:

$s_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)$ converges uniformly to $s(x)$.

And $a_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^ng_k(x)$ converges uniformly to $a(x)$.

Therefore, $\sup_{x\in X}|s_n(x)-s(x)|<\epsilon$ as $n>N_1$.

And $\sup_{x\in X}|a_n(x)-(x)|<\epsilon$ as $n>N_2$.

Now consider

$\sup_{x\in X}|s_n(x)+a_n(x)-s(x)-a(x)| \le \sup_{x\in X}|s_n(x)-s(x)|+\sup_{x\in X}|a_n(x)-a(x)|<2\epsilon$ as $n>max(N_1,N_2)$.

Hence

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty [ f_n(x)+g_n(x)] = s(x)+a(X)$ converges uniformly on $x\in X$.

---

**Definitions**
Series converges uniformly on $X$ if the sequence of partial sums converges uniformly on $X$.

**Definitions**
A sequence $f_n$ is said to converge uniformly on $X$ to function $f$ if 
$$\sup_{x\in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \rightarrow 0 \text{ as  } n \rightarrow \infty$$

Comment: If this is homework, *please say so*. It would also help you in any case to show your working so far :)

Comment: @Shaun This isn't a homework. I have shown what I've done so far. Please let me know if there's any error.

Comment: @Shaun Let me know if it's correct. Not fully sure~ :p

Comment: @Dosomemaths: That's much better, thank you. You've left a few things undefined though so it's hard to evaluate your working.

Comment: @Shaun What are the few things that needs more explanation?

Comment: Nope, sorry. My mistake. That looks okay, but I'm busy right now. Someone will give an answer soon, though, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much got it. I would be a little more careful with quantifying $\epsilon$, $n$, $N_1$, and $N_2$: instead of writing

> "Therefore, $\sup_x |a_n(x) - a(x)|<\epsilon$ as $n>N_1$,"

for example, maybe write something like

> "Therefore, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N_1$ so that $\sup_x|a_n(x) - a(x)|<\epsilon$ for any $n>N_1$.

This also would clean up your proof of uniform convergence of $\sum (f+g)$, e.g.:

> "Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. There exist $N_1,N_2$ such that .... choose $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Then if $n>N$, ....."